# spring boot jpa data fetching based on recent date entry and user id value?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Is the following declaration correct?
**findFirst2ByOrderByCreatedAtDescAndByUser();**
While running the project its giving error in the startup that the property is anduser not defined.

@Entity
public class otptable{

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(10)")
private String otp;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userUuid", referencedColumnName = "id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user"))
private Users user;//its a foreign key relation field


@CreationTimestamp
@CreatedDate
private LocalDateTime createdAt;

}
```

Comment: you should provide more information. To start with what are you trying to Query, how does your entity class look like

Comment: ok sir sure i ll add the entity layer in code

Comment: Direction keywords `Asc` and `Desc`, in addition to indicating the sort, also separate the properties.

Comment: i cant get clear understanding. Kindly give a sample of it.